# Посимвольная проверка символов с клавиатуры со строкой массива

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-events

Вешаю **eventListener ('keyup')** для окна. При нажатии на кнопку, кейКод записывается в массив. Так же есть строка **"Typing text #1"**. Мне нужно сравнивать посимвольно введенный кейКод с первой буквой текста, для этого разбил строку на массив, а каждый кейКод преобразовываю в символ с помощью **String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)**, но есть проблема. В тексте есть заглавная буква и знак решетки, но при зажатии шифт + 3, выводится кейКод отдельно двух клавиш. Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: А общая задача какая? Получить от пользователя текст и сравнить с имеющимся текстом?

Comment: Неа.  Я делаю игру типа клавогонок, и при вводе текста надо каждый полученний символ сравнивать с строки

Comment: Может тогда брать `e.key`, а служебные клавиши пропускать?

Comment: Ну просто дело в том, что в тексте встречаются символы типа #$!№, и их тоже надо вводить

Comment: Символы все можно ввести в `e.key` будет и "K" и "#" и любые символы. Просто в пару с этим событием пройдет и еще одно, со служебной клавишей "Shift". Это событие не использовать и все.

Comment: Тьфу, я и не знал, что есть e.key. Я блин получал keyCode и переводил его в символ. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127033/discussion-between-leonid-and-vova).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема со служебной клавишей `Shift`, то можно ее исключать из обработки. А заглавные буквы и символ `#` будет храниться в `e.key`.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    let key = e.key;
    if(key !== 'Shift'){
            console.log(key);
    }
})
```